# How can i open PDF (In new window, or download it) in Post Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, pdf, razor-pages

The first one of the following examples is working perfectly. The second one istn working, the pdf is saved to the database but the Onpost Method isnt working

**1.( Working Example)** I am doing this with `_taget="blank` and calling an empty Razor-Page.
The code looks like this.

**HTML**

```
 <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggleToolTip="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
    title="Anzeigen" asp-page="/Invoices/DisplayInvoiceAsPdf" asp-route-invoiceId="@item.Nr" target="_blank">
 <i class="fa-solid fa-download"></i>
 </a>
```

**Code behind of empty Razor-Page:**

```
public class DisplayInvoiceAsPdfModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IDataRepository _DataRepository;

    public DisplayInvoiceAsPdfModel(IDataRepository DataRepository)
    {
        _DataRepository = DataRepository;
    }
    public Kopfdaten Kopfdaten { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
    {

        Kopfdaten = await _DataRepository.GetDataById(id);
        if(Kopfdaten.Pdf == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return File(Kopfdaten.Pdf, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

When i click on the Button the Pdf will be opened in a new tab (In Google Chrome).

**2.(Not working Example):** Im Creating a Preview Pdf in the OnPostmMethod, The PDf should be opened after the Pdf is created and stored to My database. I want to open Pdf with  `await OnPostPDf(id)`

```
 if (y == "OK")
     {
        //Ok=> Open Pdf in new Tab
        await OnPostPDF(id);
           
        if (testBool == true)
        {
            //Refresh page ,error 
            return RedirectToPage("Invoice", new { Id = adrId});
        }
        else
        {
            //Post 
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
     }
```

**OnpostPdf looks like this:**

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostPDF(int id)
    {
        Kopfdaten kopfdaten = new Kopfdaten();
        kopfdaten = await _DataRepository.DataById(id);
        if (kopfdaten.Pdf == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return File(kopfdaten.Pdf, "application/pdf");
    }
```

**Get Data ById**

```
 public async Task<Kopfdaten> GetDataById(int id)
    {

        try
        {
            return await _Context.Kopfdaten.FindAsync(id);                        
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Couldn't retrieve entities: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

**Kopfdaten model:**

```
public partial class Kopfdaten
   {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int InVoiceNumber { get; set; }
      public string Text { get; set; }
      public int AdressId{ get; set; }
      public byte[] Pdf { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Does the file exists within your project or folder? What `kopfdaten` returns?

Comment: @Md The file exists on my SQL-Server Database

Comment: what `kopfdaten` returns? In addition, are you getting error or anything?

Comment: `kopfdaten` is a Model with data from an Invoice, kopfdaten.Pdf is a ByteArray wich i decode in a PDF. There is no Error, Just nothing happening.

Comment: Im Calling the OnPostPDF inside my OnPostAsync, could this be the problem?

Comment: I Posted it under my Question.

Comment: If your aplication folder doesn't contains any `kopfdaten.Pdf` file then it will do nothing. Firstly, you should have `pdf` then you can return that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "How can I open PDF (In new window, or download it) in Post Method"

So there are 3 ways to handle this kind of scenario.

***Way: 1 When You have an existing PDF file in your application folder***

In this scenario, suppose you have `PDF file` in your application folder like below:

[image]

**Solution:**

```
public ActionResult DisplayPDFFromExistingFile()
        {
            string physicalPath = "wwwroot/KironGitHub.pdf";
            byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPath);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
            return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");

        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

***Way: 2 When you want to display PDF on your browser from database Model***

**Solution:**

```
 public ActionResult DisplayPdfOnBrowserFromDatabaseList()
        {
            
            var data = _context.Members.ToList();
            var pdf = data.ToPdf();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdf);
            return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");

        }
```

**Note:** To handle this scenario you need to use [`3rd party Nuget package`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) which is [`ArrayToPdf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) You can search on `Nuget package` on your visual studio. You can also check the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/mustaddon/ArrayToPdf). Finally need to add `using ArrayToPdf;` on top.

**Output:**

[image]

***Way: 3 When you want to download PDF on your browser from database model or existing file***

**Solution:**

```
public ActionResult DownloadPDFOnBrowser()
    {

        var data = _context.Members.ToList();
        var byteArray = data.ToPdf();

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

        string mimeType = "application/pdf";
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, mimeType)
        {
            FileDownloadName = "DatabaseListToPdf.pdf"
        };


    }
```

**Note:** As described above we need to add `using ArrayToPdf;` on top. To handle this scenario you need to use [`3rd party Nuget package`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) which is [`ArrayToPdf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArrayToPdf) You can search on `Nuget package` on your visual studio. See the screenshot below:

[image]

You can also check the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/mustaddon/ArrayToPdf)

**Output:**

[image]

These are the use case scenario of how we could handle (`PDF`) the issue you are having.

Comment: Glad  to assist you on this.